# bystats Command for Summarizing one Variable by Another

Tags: r

I wanted to get some input on my solution for this question. I was requested to summarize the birth weight of patients by their race using the bystats command.

```
bystats(SB_xlsx$bwt, SB_xlsx$race, fun=function(x) c(Mean=mean(x), Median=median(x), Mode=mode(x), SD=sd(x), quantile(x)))
## 
##  c(1, 40, 1, 121, 40, 121, 1, 1) of SB_xlsx$bwt by SB_xlsx$race 
## 
##                 N     Missing Mean               Median Mode     
## black           "369" "0"     "1071.72628726287" "1100" "numeric"
## native american "16"  "0"     "986.5625"         "1035" "numeric"
## oriental        "4"   "0"     "1150"             "1140" "numeric"
## white           "257" "0"     "1151.08171206226" "1200" "numeric"
## NA              "23"  "2"     "875.217391304348" "750"  "numeric"
## ALL             "669" "2"     "1093.88639760837" "1120" "numeric"
##                 SD                 0%    25%    50%    75%      100%  
## black           "272.51016811411"  "400" "850"  "1100" "1300"   "1500"
## native american "261.984215491443" "400" "920"  "1035" "1127.5" "1450"
## oriental        "164.519502390041" "960" "1080" "1140" "1210"   "1360"
## white           "231.682983871944" "510" "975"  "1200" "1330"   "1580"
## NA              "336.487465188897" "540" "585"  "750"  "1070"   "1490"
## ALL             "265.224747555532" "400" "900"  "1120" "1310"   "1580"
```

The summary requested was vague, but this was the information obtained in lecture, so I also went with the same information. I'm just wanting to make sure I did not miss any command, so that my summary I have typed after getting this info comparing means and quantiles is accurate.

Comment: I think you need some more information, for me it was not very clear what you want. But since you are working with summary measures, you could use other functions and compare the results. summary(), dplyr::summarize() for example.

Comment: What package contains bystats?